# Android Studio Emulator isn't opening. Showing "enable VT-x in your BIOS settings"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just instaled android studio and when I run the app, the emulator doesn't open and shows the error. I have attached the screenshot of the error. I am using MacBook Pro 2012. Recently I have installed 8GB RAM to the Mac. Now the total RAM is 2GB+8GB. Is it due to the new RAM installed? or it's a different thing?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nitin, Did you resolve the issue? if so please share how did you resolve. I am also seeing similar kind of message.

Answer (score 2):

When you use third-party products that incude Intel VT-x virtualization technology, an alert message might tell you that VT-x support is locked by the firmware on your Mac.
You might also notice that VT-x support is disabled when you use third-party virtualization applications on your Mac like VMWare Fusion or Parallels Desktop.

You can fix this issue by making sure that your Mac has the latest software updates available:

For Mac Pro (Original), install Mac Pro EFI Firmware Update 1.2 or later.

For reference, kindly go through below link. 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203296